# Save trace file from Android emulator of Android Studion to the system using adb

Tags: android, adb, emulation, trace

I want to save trace file of an App from Android emulator of Android Studio to my system using the following command:

```
adb pull /sdcard/Android/Trace1.perfetto-trace /C:/Users/MyAccount/TraceFile/
```

But it showing the error `/system/bin/sh: adb: inaccessible or not found`

How can i resolve this issue?

Thank you!

I have tried many other ways to upload the trace file to google drive but it is not working,
and I have also tried to locate file from Device Explorer but my trace file is not showing in that directory.
I have saved the trace file in `/sdcard/Android/`
I have used terminal of Android Studio as well as Cygwin64 Terminal, but nothing solved my issue.

My Emulator configuration is as follows:

```
Emulator Version: 31.3.10-8807927
Android version: 11.0 (R) - API 30
Pixel 2 API 30
```

Anyone please help.

Thank you.

Comment: The external app data path is `/sdcard/Android/data/<app-packagename>`. So assuming `Trace1.perfetto-trace` is your app packagename your path misses `data/` in the middle.

Comment: No this path indicates the location where my trace file saved. Trace1.perfetto-trace is my trace file which is saved inside /sdcard/Android/ location. Is there anything wrong? Kindly please help

Comment: I would first make sure the trace has been written at all (use `adb shell` and use Linux commands to list the files in that dir). The path you have chosen is not designed to be written by apps, so if you have ignored some exceptions it could be the case that the file wasn't written at all because of missing permissions. Also make sure you are familiar with Android scoped storage and the limitations that have been introduced in Android 10. Since Scoped storage is mandatory writing a file the correct way and in the correct place has become a little more complicated,